# Change table cell from text to input value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table in CRUD loaded from database, I want table rows to be editable by converting table cell to input field preserving cell text as input value. I am using `jQuery` for that.

So far, I can add input field inside `<td>` tag. But data from all the cells becomes value of each input instead of becoming value of their respective input fields.

Here is my code...

```js
$("#parEdit").click(function() {
    $(this).text("Update");
    $(this).closest('tr').children().wrapInner('<input type="text" value = ' + $('td').text() + '></input>');
})
```

My table looks like this...

| ID | Name | Position | Marks | Edit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ahmad | 6th | 525 | Edit Button |

After pressing the Edit button, the output is like this...

| ID | Name | Position | Marks | Edit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1Ahmad6th525 | 1Ahmad6th525 | 1Ahmad6th525 | 1Ahmad6th525 | Update Button |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need apply the wrap to each td, your original code inserted every td text.

```
$("#parEdit").click(function(){
   $(this).text("Update");
   $(this).closest('tr').children().each(function(){
      $(this).wrapInner('<input type="text" value = ' + $(this).text() + '></input>');
   });
});
```

Comment: You have missing closing tags for the click function. Thanks for the help